# User management problems with Microservices

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, microservices

I have read many articles but still could not get the  answer to a simple question. How  do you change roles and stop user access with microservice architecture?

When you have some business services separated from auth service, then you pass all auth info like roles in jwt payload. That is fine. But what if I changed the role or banned the user? It will take affect only when jwt expires. So I need very short lived jwt. In mono app I just ask DB with every request for roles and some other user info. I can cache it like in redis for 1 min. This will work fine. But I have never seen implementation that update jwt every minute.

How do you solve this issue with microservices?

Comment: That's the downside of using JWTs. One alternative may be to fetch permissions from a database/separate service when you need to verify them. Obviously, there's also a question whether you really need to refresh user's permissions "instantly" or it's fine to wait until their token expire.

Comment: Fetching permissions for a database is fine but from http service is not fine.  Apart for roles there is also the question of password change, that should invalidate token immediately. And it looks like Microservice architecture with separate DBs does not address this requirement. So I wonder if there are any real life microservice implementations with separate auth service at all.